# As3 tooltip orientation changes when I place the contents in a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, tooltip

I have around 20 buttons that together make a map of USA. I am using AS3 tool tip, which display name of region on mouse-over. I want to create a movieclip which will house all these 20 buttons and their actions(basically put everything under one movieclip).

But when I do that everything works fine but the tool tip gets dispalced.
It appears almost at the edge of the stageAny way to make it appear near the mouse cursor?

Thanks in advance.

Code I am using for tool tip is:

```
Button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOverHandler1);

function mouseOverHandler1(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    //creating a new tooltip instance
    var tooltip:Tooltip = new Tooltip();

    //we tell the holder to hold our tooltip
    holder = tooltip;

    //adding text to the tooltip
    holder.descr.text = "1 - Button";

    //positioning the tooltip on the stage
    holder.x = stage.mouseX  - 10;
    holder.y = stage.mouseY - 15;

    //adding the tooltip to the stage
    addChild(tooltip);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just corrected the code in my answer.

Comment: this code will only work if holder is a child of stage. add holder to the stage and your problem should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `globalToLocal`

Create a `Point` object and use it to translate the position of the tooltip from global (Stage) scope to local (DisplayObject) scope.

```
var Offset:Point = globalToLocal(new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY));

holder.x = Offset.x;
holder.y = Offset.y;
```

Comment: thanks for replying. Do i need to change anything in the code which you have given? I tried it as it is but does not change my tool tip possition, it is still showing my tool tip at the same locationa and not near the cursor. :(

Comment: You may need to edit the Offset variable. It depends on your MovieClip hierarchy. Maybe, change `globalToLocal` to `holder.globalToLocal`. Sometimes is a little bit hard to identify the correct conversion setup.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a simple application(despite its size) of a `Sprite` object(`Circles` object) with children that are also `Sprite` objects(`Circle` objects), each one with 2 child objects(`_circleShape` and `_toolTip`). When you roll over a `Circle` object, the `_toolTip` appears and its 'x' and 'y' properties are respectively set to the current `mouseX` and `mouseY` properties of the `Circle` object. I put all the code in the same file so you could simply copy and paste the entire code sample into your document class and run it. Ideally you should separate the code sample into the appriopriate class files:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var circles:Circles = new Circles();
            addChild(circles);

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

internal class Circles extends Sprite
{
    public function Circles()
    {
        var horizontalSpace:int = 50;
        var verticalSpace:int = 50;

        var i:uint = 1;

        for (var y:uint = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            for (var x:uint = 0; x < 5; x++)
            {
                var circle:Circle = new Circle();
                circle.x = (x * circle.width) + (x * horizontalSpace);
                circle.y = (y * circle.height) + (y * verticalSpace);
                circle.toolTip.text = "This is Circle " + String(i);
                addChild(circle);

                circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onCircleMouseOver);

                i++;

            }// end for

        }// end for

    }// end function

    private function onCircleMouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var circle:Circle = Circle(e.currentTarget);

        setChildIndex(circle, numChildren - 1);

    }// end function

}// end class

internal class Circle extends Sprite
{
    private var _toolTip:ToolTip;
    private var _circleSprite:Sprite;

    public function get toolTip():IText
    {
        return _toolTip;

    }// end function

    public function Circle()
    {
        _circleSprite = new Sprite();
        _circleSprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
        _circleSprite.graphics.drawCircle(50, 50, 50);
        _circleSprite.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(_circleSprite);

        _toolTip = new ToolTip();
        _toolTip.visible = false;
        _toolTip.mouseEnabled = false;
        _toolTip.mouseChildren = false;
        addChild(_toolTip);

        _circleSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseOver);
        _circleSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
        _circleSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseOut);

    }// end function

    private function onMouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        _toolTip.visible = true;

    }// end function

    private function onMouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (contains(_toolTip))
        {
            _toolTip.x = mouseX;
            _toolTip.y = mouseY - _toolTip.height;

        }// end if

    }// end function

    private function onMouseOut(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        _toolTip.visible = false

    }// end function

}// end class

internal class ToolTip extends Sprite implements IText
{
    private var _textField:TextField;

    public function get text():String
    {
        return _textField.text;

    }// end function

    public function set text(text:String):void
    {
        _textField.text = text;

    }// end function

    public function ToolTip()
    {
        graphics.beginFill(0xFFFF00, 0.8);
        graphics.lineStyle(1, 0, 0.8);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 20);

        _textField = new TextField();
        _textField.maxChars = 20;
        _textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        _textField.x = 5;
        addChild(_textField);

    }// end function

}// end interface

internal interface IText
{
    function get text():String
    function set text(text:String):void

}// end interface
```

I hope by using this as a guideline that it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for replying back. I still write the code on timeline, I really dont know how to execute the code you gave... :( the problem I am having is that when i embed the As3 code and the button which display tooltip in a movieclip, instead of showing it near the cursor it displays it someother place.